# Random Sampling limit by file size

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, statistics, random

Is is possible to generate a data set by random sampling and limit the output's size?

I have an input of ~260MB text file and I want to generate files of different sizes (~1MB, ~5MB, ~10MB, ...), wherein the entries are randomly generated from from the source file.

What's the best approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to read the file and skip lines as you output them.

You use the modulus (%) to get every nth row.  Set the skip rows to the size of your sample file / size of require file.  For example 260MB/5MB = 52, so set the % operator to 52 and you should get a file about 5mb.

Here is a quick example:

```
        StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\bigfile.csv"));

        StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("c:\\smallfile.csv"));

        int rowCount = 0;
        while(!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = inputFile.ReadLine();

            if (rowCount % 1000 == 1)
                outputFile.WriteLine(line);

            rowCount++;
        }
```

With randomizer as requested.  With this version, work out how many rows will make 5mb (I've put 100,000).  This will then loop randomly though the file until it's loaded 100,000 rows.  If it finishes before getting all the rows, it just starts to read the file again.  This will be 'very' random.

```
        StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\bigfile.csv"));

        StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(File.OpenWrite("c:\\smallfile.csv"));

        Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());

        int rowCount = 0;
        int rowsUsed = 0;
        skipCount = rnd.Next(1, 2000);

        while(rowsUsed < 100000)
        {
         while(!inputFile.EndOfStream || rowsUsed > 100000)
         {
            string line = inputFile.ReadLine();

            if (rowCount % skipCount == 1)
            {
                outputFile.WriteLine(line);
                skipCount = rnd.Next(1, 2000);
            }

            rowCount++;
         }

         StreamReader inputFile = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead("c:\\bigfile.csv"));
        }
```

Comment: So this generates the same 5MB file everytime. right? I need 5MB files that MAY vary, but not the same everytime. My initial implementation is to choose a random item and skip _n_ number of items. But there's no way I can determine the file size of the output.

How can I generate different contents for each file generated? Or is there a way to predetermine/estimate the file size before writing?